# Dynamic values in percentage format in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know making Objective C variable values in percentage format. I am getting 6 values dynamically. Sometimes values might increase more than 100. For ex: Avalue=143, Bvalue=450, Cvalue=76, Dvalue=98, Evalue=123, Fvalue=56
how can i format each value under percentage format?

```
(Avalue * 100)/100.f
(Bvalue * 100)/100.f
(Cvalue * 100)/100.f
(Dvalue * 100)/100.f
(Evalue * 100)/100.f
(Fvalue * 100)/100.f
```

Is this proper way of doing it?

Comment: Multiplied value by 100 and divided the result of it by 100 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: arent they already in percentage amounts? just add a "%" on the end when you print it...

Comment: My question is not about printing, Am I making the values in percentage format properly?

Comment: just add a `%` character in it? not sure what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, percentage numbers are  in essence fractions. In mathematics, a [percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100.

if you want to compare numbers like in your case, compare each numbers to the sum oaf all value, then set the sum as 100%.

```
float sumAllValues =  (Avalue + Bvalue + ...);
float aValuePercent = (Avalue / sumAllValues) * 100.f
```

you can format that percentage number with NSNumberFormatter

```
NSString *result1 = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aValuePercent];
                                                    numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
```

btw: why the variables begin with a Uppercase?

-Edit-

When you divide integers, keep in mind that integers divided by integer results integer.
I wrote a short example for the console.

```
 NSInteger a = 5;
 NSInteger b = 6;
 NSInteger c = a * 100 / b;
 NSInteger d = a / b * 100;
// example with conversion al values to float 
float e = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:a] floatValue] / [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:b] floatValue] * 100;
NSLog(@"resulting int c: %lu", c);
NSLog(@"resulting int d: %lu", d);
NSLog(@"resulting float e: %f", e);


2017-02-14 19:36:54.897 IntegerTest[2291:1238166] resulting int c: 83
2017-02-14 19:36:54.898 IntegerTest[2291:1238166] resulting int d: 0
2017-02-14 19:36:54.898 IntegerTest[2291:1238166] resulting float e: 83.333328
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

You see, when you multiply the first integer with 100 and the divide, you get 83.

The other way round (what is mathematically correct), first the division and after the multiply, you get 0, because 5/6 is less than 1 and the integer value is set to 0. Since multiplying 0 by any other value remains 0, the result is 0.

- EDIT AGAIN -
  the code from console is written with plain integers, but in essence they are the same as your values. First the multiplication, then the division.
  `NSInteger aPercentage = (Avalue * 100) / Bvalue;`

or cast all values to floats. like so:

```
float aValueFloat = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:Avalue] floatValue];
```

- EDIT AGAIN -
  This was only for example reasons. Value is only the divisor because I do not know, to wash value you want to compare those values. In this example Avalue is compared to Bvalue, say Avalue is percent from Bvalue.
  If you only want to print out Avlue = 143 in 143% then:

  ```
  NSInteger aValue = 146;
  NSString *aValuePercentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%%", aValue];
  NSLog(@"%@", aValuePercentString);
  ```

Output: 2017-02-15 16:52:26.346 test[2132:1070601] 146%

Note1: This works with values as Integers. If the values are NSNumbers use %@ instead of %ld.

Note2: Value is not an Integer anymore but a string.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If `Avalue` and `Bvalue`are integers you should do the multiplication first to avoid integer division, e. g. `100.0 * Avalue / Bvalue`.

Comment: Could you please update the answer including "macmoonshine" answer. Because Avalue, Bvalue etc are integers.

Comment: Done. I wrote a short console program to clarify the requested answer.

Comment: I am bit confused. Should I use the code mentioned in answer or in console? Because, I see the example code in the answer shows "(Avalue / sumAllValues) * 100.f"  and in console sample shows "c = a * 100 / b". I am bit confused on this. I mean, Do I need to add sum of all values and use it as divider with each value (or) this way "c = a * 100 / b", what is c and d here ? As I told, I will have couple of values more than "100" as well.

Comment: The code from console is for clarifying reason. I would point out, that with integers, you better first multiply the value with 100 and then divide.

Comment: Ok thank you. I would use like this, float aValuePercent = ( (Avalue * 100) / sumAllValues) * 100.f

Comment: I am still not sure, why should I divide Avalue with Bvalue ((Avalue * 100) / Bvalue), 100.0 * Avalue / Bvalue ?